# Laravel: How to pass from Ajax succes to vuejs

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to pass object from Ajax to View and using this in @foreach loop. Same as if I return view('someview', ['mat', $mat])

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Material;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MaterialsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.home');
    }

    public function getAllMaterials()
    {  
        $materials = Material::all();

        return $materials;
    }
}

  //Material usage button
    $('#add_materials_btn').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/materials',
            data: null,
            success:function(mat) {
                return mat;
            }
        });
    });
```

@foreach($mat as $m)

@endforeach

Comment: Why would you want to use ajax on your view? You can inject the values you need on your view from your controller straight away. If after the view loaded you need to dynamically fetch content, you can use Ajax and implement an API using [Laravel API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#introduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use ajax to pass data from laravel controller to vue.js. In order to achieve this, you have to create APIs which will let you pass data from laravel controller to vue.js
you can check this link out it's easy and helpful
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-send-data-from-laravel-controller-to-vuejs

Comment: okay, thanks for help. so I need manually to each object to view

Comment: No problem. Do you want your data in vue.js or laravel blade template ?